# swap image in splash screen

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am just starting to develop an windows app.I want to load different image when an application starts in landscape/portrait mode . There should be different image in splash screen on the basis of whether it starts in landscape mode , snapped mode or portrait mode.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an extended splash screen which is responsive to orientation changes:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx

To maximize the benefit of the extended splash screen you should minimize the time the default splash screen is shown. There are some articles that tackle this topic:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/hh994639.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994640.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Fred writes, the initial splash screen displays until the app's code takes over, so the app doesn't have any run-time control over the initial splash screen. The app can provide different images for different resolutions, languages, contrast modes, etc. but not based on orientation. See [How to name resources using qualifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324(v=win.10).aspx)

Once the app is loaded and running then it can manage its own extended splash screen as Fred describes. The extended splash screen can be fully customised since the app is active and running code.